# Unity: Is it possible to get the data from an async-loaded scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, asynchronous, load, scene

I'm creating a game where the user can edit the levels.
This is done in "edit-mode", which is a single scene. Im trying to avoid have to create an edit-scene for each seperate level.
All the relevant data is saved to files on the user-device and loaded when needed.

Now the problem: On each level I have some premade waypoints, but these need to be saved to files on first load.

I was hoping to use the SceneManagement.LoadSceneAsync for each level I create and save all this data to files so it can be loaded in the editMode scene.

So my question is, can you load scenes in the background while displaying a loading screen and then reference the data that is loaded in the background in anyway?

I was trying something like this:

```c#
UnityEngine.AsyncOperation async;

void Start()
{
    LoadScene("Level1");
    Invoke("TryGetScene", 1f);
}

void LoadScene(string _sceneName)
{
    async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(_sceneName);
    async.allowSceneActivation = false;
}

void TryGetScene()
{
    Debug.Log("trying to get scene");
    if (async.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Scene is loaded");
        foreach (GameObject go in SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Level1").GetRootGameObjects())
        {
            Debug.Log(go.name);
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems the scene needs to be the active scene before you can get any gameobjects in the scene.

Anyone here who can point me in the right direction? Is it at all possible?

Comment: what exactly do you need it for? You could try to instead load the "background" Scene `Additive` and let it load completely. If you are using a `ScreenSpace Overlay` Canvas for the loading screen it will be in front anyway. Then you can do whatever you want and later either unload the background scene again or the loading scene depending on your needs. In short: Afaik it is impossible to address anything from a scene until it is fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hugo, I think this addition will be enough for me to solve the issue. I need it because I'm creating a lot of levels with preset waypoints (it will be an ATC game, so the entry and exit points of the map will be created by me). But the user will be responsible for creating all other waypoints. When I open the editMode scene, the preset waypoints should be loaded for the level the player is editing. But this information is saved on each individual Level Scene, and im trying to save it to files when the user opens the game for the first time.